# Findstr to output children and parent

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt, findstr

I am trying to organize my xml/kml file using command line. I can use `findstr "STRING" file.txt` to find the data I only need but can't seem to get the rest of the children from its parent. The kml file is structured like

```
<Placemark>
<name></name>
<description> [The sring data I need] </description>
<Point><coordinates></coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

When I run the `findstr` I only get the description data and need to get all the above, any ideas?

Comment: While maybe possible with a lot of effort, I'd strongly suggest using a Windows port of standard *nix `grep`, with which the solution boils down to `grep -A2 -B2 "STRING" file.txt`. Get it [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep -A3 -B2 "String" file.txt worked for me
thanks @zb226

Answer (score 1):

Also, pure batch

```
set "init="
set "term="
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('type yourFile.xml ^| find /I /N "placemark"') do (
  if not defined init (set /a init=%%A) else (set /a term=%%A)
)
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('type yourFile.xml ^| find /N /V "^"') do (
  if %%A GEQ %init% if %%A LEQ %term% echo/%%B
)
```

EDIT: the issue was the quote in front of `type` in the line `for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('type yourFile.xml ...`

And to write to a file

```
set "init="
set "term="
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('type yourFile.xml ^| find /I /N "placemark"') do (
  if not defined init (set /a init=%%A) else (set /a term=%%A)
)
>"myFile.txt" (
  for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('type yourFile.xml ^| find /N /V "^"') do (
    if %%A GEQ %init% if %%A LEQ %term% echo/%%B
  )
)
```

So any `echo ...` is printed to *myFile.txt*

Comment: I think this may have a syntax error, or needs escaping characters. Didn't work for me.

Comment: where do I write to file so I can see if its working because its not doing anything for me, either one.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely advise you to go for the `grep` solution when available.
Because I was interested to see how the problem could be solved with batch-file scripting—the question is tagged with `batch-file` after all—and for sake of completeness, I decided to post the script anyway.

Keep in mind that there are always some limitations/corner cases when performing string searches with batch-files.

The script will display as many lines as specified by the `lines` variable. The `offset` variable specifies on which line the string to look for is expected. Only the last match is displayed when there are multiple matches found.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=file.txt"
set "find=[The string data I need]"
set "lines=5"
set "offset=3"

for /f "delims=:" %%e in ('findstr /n /c:"%find%" "%source%"') do (
  set /a position=%%e-offset
)

if not defined position (
  echo No matches found for: %find%
  exit /b
)

for /f "usebackq skip=%position% delims=" %%e in ("%source%") do (
  if !count!0 lss %lines%0 (
    echo %%e
    set /a count+=1
  )
)
```

Comment: it just closes, under find do i need to put my string inside the [ ]? or just after the =?

Comment: Place the string that you need to find after the equal sign. Personally, I find it more convenient to execute the script from an existing command prompt window since you can simply press the arrow up key to execute it again. If you prefer to execute scripts from Window Explorer, you could place a `pause` command at the end of the file and before any `exit` commands.